# I am trying to make a script that moves my GameObject for sometime and then stops it for 2 seconds but it does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a script that moves my GameObject for sometime and then stops it for 2 seconds.

But my code does make it run a while then stop but then it goes in an endless loop of not doing anything at all

Here is my code;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class Enemyai : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public int timer = 100000;
    public int Abstimer = 100000;
    public bool running = true;
    
    public float speed = 5;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        if (timer==0)
        {
            timer = Abstimer;
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
            running = false;
            Invoke("attack", 2);




        }


        if (running == true)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
            this.transform.position += transform.right * -speed * Time.deltaTime;
            timer--;
        }

        

    }
    void attack()
    {
        
        running = true;
    }
```

`

Comment: Can you check from the inspector to see if your Abstimer is set to 100000 or 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well .. you know you currently make it wait for `100000` **frames**

=> with a normal frame rate of about 60 frames per second that makes  about `1667` seconds - aka 27 Minutes - of waiting...

What you would rather do is

- not use frame rate dependent code but seconds
- use a reasonable amount of time ^^

Like e.g.

```
public class Enemyai : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    // This would mean 3 seconds
    public float Abstimer = 3f;
    public float speed = 5;

    void Update()
    {    
        if (timer<=0)
        {
            timer = Abstimer;
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
            running = false;
            Invoke(nameof(attack),  2);
        }
        if (running)
        {               
            this.transform.position -= transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            timer-= Time.deltaTime:
        }
    }

    void attack()
    {
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        running = true;
    }
}
```

---

Maybe easier to handle might be a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```
public class Enemyai : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    // This would mean 3 seconds
    public float Abstimer = 3f;
    public float speed = 5;

    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);

            for(var timer = 0f; timer < Abstimer; timer += Time.deltaTime)
            {
                transform.position -= transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }

            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
    } 
}
```

---

Either way have in mind you still need to actually adjust the value of `Abstimer` in the Inspector not only in code

Comment: Yep it works just like i wanted it to thanks again

Comment: @Casseia Don't forget that when your your question has been properly answered, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. This signals to everyone that the question is solved and it also gives some fun internet points.